# Google Feature Graphic - can't resize image for 1024px by 500px

Tags: image, google-play

I have an image that I want to resize and use it for Google Play Store Feature Graphic.

Google requires the image size 1024 px by 500px. I am on Windows 11. I use SnagIt, Photos, FastStoneCapture, and GIMP

If I use any of these tools, then the image is not resized by 1024 px by 500px.

Instead, the graphic tool resizes image to 1024 px by 576px or 889px by 500px.

If I try to upload either 1024 px by 576px or 889px by 500px, then Google Play store complains that my image is not properly sized.

Please help if you can.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I found the website:hotpot.ai which will generate the appropriate image sizes for the Google play store. All Google errors about incorrect images sizes will be gone after using this website. Using regular software tools will not work to create the required image size.

Thank You

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).